# SQL Server Restrict Access to Database by Windows Authentication Mode

Tags: sql-server

I am facing problem regarding database permissions. I have created my database named `FCProject`. I created a login for that database in SQL Server Management Studio. My login is working fine but all I want to restrict access to `FCProject` database through users who can log in to SQL Server through Windows authentication mode.

Because I want only FC login to be able to view or modify data of FC database in SQL Server Management Studio.

I have tried creating a login through Management Studio. Is there any problem in creating login? Or something else? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up two things that should be kept separate here:

1. A **login** is on the **server** level - it gives an account (a Windows account, or a SQL Server specific account) the permission to connect to this server
2. Each database can then define **user** for its own use - based on those logins.

So in your case, what you need to do is to:

1. create a number of *logins* on the server-level
2. create *users* in your `FCLogin` database for just those logins

and then you're fine - only **those accounts** that you've defined explicitly can access your `FCLogin` database and use it.

See the [Stairway to SQL Server security](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/110890/) series of articles on SQL Server Central (very well worth registering for their contents!) which explains all the ins and outs in great detail

Comment: what is meant by Login on Server Level?

Comment: As I tried to explain: a **login** is for the **whole server** (not a single database) - once you have a login, *then* you can define one or more **user** for your database in question

Comment: i have a login named FC , now where i can define FC user for my FCProject database?

Comment: @WaqasAli: in your SQL Server Mgmt Studio, go to the `FCLogin` database, and under `FCLogin > Security > Users` you can define the database users based on your logins

Comment: i have defined there my Login FC, but i am also accessing database FCProject when i log in through windows authentication mode. i want it to be only accessed when i log in through FCLogin

Comment: @WaqasAli: only **users** that are defined in your `FCLogin` database can access that database (plus system administrators). So if you want to prevent a particular Windows auth login from accessing this database - just don't create a user for it in your database